# sklearn RandomForestRegressor: number of trainable parameters

Tags: parameters, scikit-learn, regression, random-forest

Is there a way to extract from sklearn RandomForestRegressor the (effective) number of trainable parameters that were fit during model training?

The number of trainable parameters can be used to compare complexities of two models. Also, it can be used to estimate number of degrees of freedom in chi^2 distribution.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Are you talking about [these parameters](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html)? Please explain more clearly

Comment: I am asking about parameters, which are optimized during model training. For example, for a linear regression y=a0+a1*x1+a2*x2 those are (a0,a1,a2), i.e. the model has 3 trainable parameters.

Comment: I have the same question, did you come up with a good estimate??

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**: `n_params = sum(tree.tree_.node_count for tree in model.estimators_) * 5`

---

The [`RandomForestRegressor`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html) has an `estimators_` attribute which is populated with the list of all decision trees after fitting.
In turn, each [`DecisionTreeRegressor`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor.html) has in turn a `tree_` attribute containing a representation of the binary decision tree.
According to [this tutorial](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/tree/plot_unveil_tree_structure.html), each binary tree is completely described using four vectors, each of equal length being the number of nodes:

- `children_left`: id of the left child of the node or -1 if leaf node
- `children_right`: id of the right child of the node or -1 if leaf node
- `feature`: feature used for splitting node, encoded as integer
- `threshold`: threshold value for splitting node
- `value`: the constant prediction value at each leaf.

I exclude `n_node_samples` and `impurity` from the computation, because their are informational and not necessary to build the tree.

Thus, the total number of parameters is the sum of the number of nodes of all estimators in the ensemble, times five.

#### Working example

```py
import numpy as np
import sklearn.ensemble

# Mock regression problem.
N = 10000
X = np.random.rand(N, 4)
y = np.mean(X, axis=1)
model = (
    sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor(
        n_estimators=100,
        min_samples_leaf=11,
        n_jobs=4,
    )
    .fit(X, y)
)
# Each binary tree is described by left & righ children, feature, threshold, and value for each node.
n_params = sum(tree.tree_.node_count for tree in model.estimators_) * 5
print(f"Total number of parameters: {n_params:d}")
```

Output:

`Total number of parameters: 442210`

#### Notes

- The total number of parameters increases when decreasing `min_samples_leaf` because the trees become deeper.
- The exact same works for [`RandomForestClassifier`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html).

Answer (score -2):

After fitting  `RandomForestRegressor` you can access `feature_importances_` which indicates how important feature was when making the split,  and `n_features_` how many features in total were used for the fitting.

Comment: I am _**not**_ asking how many features were used by a model. The input data is model independent and one does not even need to have a model to be able to tell how many input features a given data set has. I am asking how many (effective) _**trainable**_ parameters a given random forest model has. `feature_importances_` simply contains all the features in the input data set and `n_features_` just tells their number.

Comment: There is no real "coefficient" in tree based regression. The only useful information which you can extract is which feature was used to get split. In standard classification, a decision tree is built top-down from a root node and involves separating data in ti subsets that contain instances with similar values. In a regression regressor is fitted to a real valued number using independent variables. Later on independent variable splits further in to several points. After this  SSE error is calculated, the variable which results in minimum SSE is selected as a node.

Comment: I hope there is a way to convert all of the split decisions into some effective number of parameters in the model in a mathematically (at least semi-) correct way. For example, if at each split only one feature is used, the value of the feature at which the data is split could be considered as one model parameter and which feature to use for the split might also contribute (perhaps fractional) number of effective parameters. Fraction of data points below a split could affect the result. There has to be an intelligent way to estimate the model complexity and I hope that someone has a good idea.

Comment: One candidate answer I have in mind, taking into account the considerations in my previous comment for a tree with a single feature at each split: sum the number of splits weighted with the fraction of all data points affected by (i.e. below) the split. This way a split which splits all the data points, contributes one (like a model parameter, which affects all the data points), while a split which splits half of all points contributes 0.5 to the result.

Comment: Have you heard about Gini impurity or information gain ? This concept are very similar on what you are describing. You can extract and visualize this information using graphviz (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html)

Comment: I am no export, but I hope it will help.